# Finding an example of two limits that do not equal $\infty$ as $x\to\infty$, but when multiplied together they equal $\infty$.

Tags: calculus, limits, infinity

I want to disprove the following statement:

> If $\displaystyle \lim_{x \to x_0^+} [f(x)g(x)] = \infty$, then either $\displaystyle \lim_{x \to x_0^+} |f(x)| = \infty$ or $\displaystyle \lim_{x \to x_0^+} |g(x)|=\infty$.

My approach is to find limits for $g(x)$ and $f(x)$ that are not equal to infinity, but when multiplied together the limit is infinity. Is there an example of this or is that wishful thinking? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4):

If you impose the condition that both $\lim_{x\to x_0^+} |f(x)|$ and $\lim_{x\to x_0^+} |g(x)|$ exist in $[0, \infty]$, then this cannot happen. Consequently, any counter-example must have the property that both of those limits fail to exist.

Here is one such counter-example:

$$ f(x)=\exp\left(\frac{1+\sin(1/x)}{x}\right)
\qquad\text{and}\qquad
g(x)=\exp\left(\frac{1-\sin(1/x)}{x}\right). $$

Then

$$ \lim_{x\to0^+}|f(x)g(x)| = \lim_{x\to 0^+} e^{2/x} = \infty, $$

but the individual limits $\lim_{x\to0^+} |f(x)|$ and $\lim_{x\to0^+} |g(x)|$ does not exist.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another one:
Let $f,g: [0,\infty) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be defined as
\begin{align*}
f(x) &= n, x = n \in \mathbb{N}\\
&= 1,\ \text{otherwise}\\
g(x) &= 1, x = n\in \mathbb{N}\\
&= x, \text{otherwise}
\end{align*}
Then we have $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0^+} |f(\frac{1}{x})|$ and $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0^+} |g(\frac{1}{x})|$ not existing, but we have $f(1/x)g(1/x) = 1/x$ which cleary goes to $\infty$

Comment: This is not written very clearly, can you explain please?

Comment: Is it fine now?